# Clockworkmod sd-ext partitioning + link2sd mount = Where is my ext partition mounted?

Tags: external-sd

HHi all...
I am desperately trying to locate my sd-ext partition in android terminal...

Where is it located?

Or, if the location changes from smartphone / rom...
How can I locate it?

I've tried fdisk -l without luck (the command doesn't exist in android)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's in

/data/sdext2

Now I just need to understand how to mount it manually.